# mysql check overlaps

Tags: mysql, sql, function, overlap

I have to write a function that has given two series A and B and returns true if any region of the elements of A overlaps with any region of the elements of B and false otherwise.

A series is defined by (bold is primary):

series(**series_id**, name, base_url, request_number, description)          request_number, description: FK(study)

and elements and regions are:

element(**series_id, elem_index**)
series_id: FK(series)

region(**series_id, elem_index, x1,y1,x2,y2**)
series_id, index: FK(element)

What I've tried so far is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckOverlap(series_id_a, series_id_b,  NUMERIC(20,0)) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
    DECLARE overlap BOOL;
    SET overlap = 0;
    SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM region WHERE series_id = series_id_a OR series_id = series_id_b
            ...


        ) INTO overlap;
    RETURN overlap;
END;
```

I basically think I need to for every interval (x1a, x2a) check all the others intervals (x1b, x2b)  (and thus I'm thinking of a join, not really sure how) check if x1a <= x2b AND x2a >= x1b (also check y1a <= y2b AND y2a >= y2b) since this is the condition for the intersection.

Example(region):

```
 id  index   x1     y1     x2  y2
| 0 |    0 |  0   | NULL | 1 | NULL |
| 0 |    1 |  0   | 1    | 0 | 1    |
| 1 |    0 |  0.5 | NULL | 2 | NULL |
| 1 |    1 |  0.5 | 0.5  | 2 | 0.5  |
| 2 |    0 |  0   | NULL | 3 | NULL |
```

[x1,x2] is an interval if the other two are NULL, otherwise its a square [x1,x2,y1,y2]. If I'm given an id 0 and an id 1, I'd detect two overlaps from elements in these two series, one between intervals with the id index pair (0,0) and (1,0), and another between the squares with the id index pair (0,1) and (1,1).

Edit: I'm using MySQL 5.1 which does not have ST_OVERLAPS or any other nice geometric types/functions.

Comment: first things first, do you absolutely need to do this in a stored procedure?

Comment: can you add sample input & output ?

Comment: yup I do, but I think the logic of the query is what is confusing me...

Comment: Yes, I'll try to add sample input and output

Comment: Have you thought about using MySQL's built in data types and functions supporting geometries rather than trying to come up with your own implementation?

Comment: what do you mean by built in data types and functions supporting geometries (sorry for my ignorance)? Like GEOMETRY types?